# Drag and Drop for Object Created by duplicateMovieClip for Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, drag-and-drop, actionscript-2

```js
i = 0;
tambah.onPress = function() {
  i = i + 1;
  duplicateMovieClip(_root.guestTable, "guestTable" + i, i);
}

for (var n = 0; i < n; n++) {
  _root["guestTable" + n].onPress = function() {
    StartDrag(this, true)
  }
  _root["guestTable" + n].onRelease = function() {
    this.stopDrag();
  }

}
```

I have created two objects which are a button and a movieclip. This button named "tambah_btn" and "guestTable_mc" for movieclip. Instance for button is "tambah" and "guestTable" for movieclip. What I would like to do is when I click the "tambah" button, a new movieclip for "guestTable" will appear. This new movieclip also capable of drag and drop where ever the user want. However, this code won't work and the movieclip seems not even duplicate and capable of drag and drop. Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your code :

- `duplicateMovieClip` it's better to be used like this :

`var mc:MovieClip = your_mc.duplicateMovieClip("mc_name", mc_depth, {mc_options});`

- Your for loop should be like this :

  `// here your iteration variable is "n" and not "i"`

  `for (var n = 0; n < i; n++) {`

But I think that you can do what you want without using a `for` loop, like this :

```
var i:int = 0;
var mc:MovieClip;

tambah.onPress = function() {

    i ++;

    // we use mc, a MovieClip object to duplicate our MovieClip, don't forget to set _x and _y to avoid that movieclips hide each other
    mc = _root.guestTable.duplicateMovieClip("guestTable" + i, i, {_x: 20, _y: i*50});

    // we can attach onPress and onRelease events directlty to the new mc
    mc.onPress = function() {
        StartDrag(this)
    } 
    // also, it's better to use onReleaseOutside to avoid that mc remains attached to the mouse
    mc.onRelease = mc.onReleaseOutside = function() {
        this.stopDrag();
    }

}
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try with your code and will update when it is done. Thanks again!